# How to create DOM model in iOS SDK

Tags: html, ios, dom

How to create DOM model in iOS SDK to update changes in HTML file? I am making a project so where I have HTML file to convert PDF format so first I create HMTL file and then programmatically update dynamic data in HMTL file.

So how do I use DOM model in Objective-C to change HTML file data?

Answer (score 1):

First create your HTML File with different tags as like "##v1#" there you want to edit your text and value. and call below function in your code.

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"page02" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:NO]encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"##v1#" withString:completeHTML];
[self.webViewTest loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

I think it would be help full for you.

Comment: Your answer text change is true but i am want  doing through DOM model every node will be tag to html file data and i am not see any ios api using dom model and any such turorial

Comment: 1)Given HTML File drag ki project (Done)
2)HTM File text change dynamicaaly through taging(DOM model) (Main Problem)
3)Html File Convert into PDF(Done)